# Executing external source in knitr and printing the external code chunk

Tags: r, knitr

I use ProjectTemplate and Knitr to produce reports.   Most of the analysis is stored in the src directory, whilst the report contains the presentation R markdown.

I would like the main text to include only the results of the analysis, and the document appendix to contain some code chunks from the analysis.  The only way I have found to achieve this is as follows:

First, run the actual analysis in the main body of the document:

````
```{r runanalysis, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
# run the analysis code to generate the objects

source('../src/rf-model-caret.R') 
```
````

Secondly, in the appendix, two knitr chunks are needed.  The first reads in the actual code (and executes it).  The second displays the code.

````
```{r analysis,  eval=TRUE, echo=FALSE}
knitr::read_chunk('../src/rf-model-caret.R')
```

```{r analysis2, ref.label="analysis", eval=FALSE, echo=TRUE}
```
````

This works but seems very inefficient because:

- The analysis has to be run twice - firstly in the source in the main document, and again in the appendix just to produce the code.
- reading a knitr chunk and then referencing it again immediately to display the code

Is there a better way to achieve the goal of executing external source in the main document and printing the code in the appendix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this:

In the main body:

````
```{r runanalysis, code=readLines('../src/rf-model-caret.R'), echo=FALSE, eval=TRUE}
```
````

In the appendix:

````
```{r runanalysis, code=readLines('../src/rf-model-caret.R'), echo=TRUE, eval=FALSE}
```
````

Comment: Yes, thank you @Yihui.  This produces the code executing in the main document and displayed in the appendix.

Is there a way to adapt the second line to read just a knitr chunk rather than the whole file?

Comment: You can choose which lines to include via the normal subsetting approach, i.e. `[]` (e.g. `readLines()[3:6]`)